# c++ brace init list as lambda argument

Tags: visual-c++, c++17

MSVC CL Version 19.14.26433.0

The situation is this:

```
auto string_tester = []( auto std_string ) { };

// creates proper std::initializer_list instance
auto  init_list = { "narrow string" };

// compiles and works
string_tester(init_list);
```

But. Should this not compile too?

```
// does not compile
string_tester({ "narrow string" } ) ;
```

Please discuss.

[Update]

Thanks for the answers, all. Apparently, lambda candidate template arguments cannot be inferred when sending init list.

I am curious. Is it "this might be removed" or "this will be removed", situation with C++20 generic lambda and this little nag?

Is this going to vanish or is this going to stay ...?

Comment: This does not work for the same reason `template<class T> void f(T a) {}` would not work with `f({ "str" });`. Turning it into a variable correctly deduces the type. I'll let somebody else find the relevant quotes from the standard.

Answer (score 1):

> **[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/4** If the placeholder is the `auto` *type-specifier*, the deduced type `T1` replacing `T` is determined using the rules for template argument deduction. Obtain `P` from `T` by replacing the occurrences of `auto` with either a new invented type template parameter `U` or, if the initialization is copy-list-initialization, with `std::initializer_list<U>`. Deduce a value for `U` using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call (**[temp.deduct.call]**), where `P` is a function template parameter type and the corresponding argument is `e`.
>
> **[temp.deduct.call]/1** Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template parameter type (call it `P`) that contains *template-parameters* that participate in template argument deduction with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`) as described below. If removing references and cv-qualifiers from `P` gives `std::initializer_list<P1>` ... for some `P1` ... and the argument is a non-empty initializer list (11.6.4), then deduction is performed instead for each element of the initializer list, taking `P1` as a function template parameter type and the initializer element as its argument... Otherwise, an initializer list argument causes the parameter to be considered a non-deduced context.

This is why `string_tester({ "narrow string" } ) ;` does not compile: the lambda has `operator()` that is a function template, and its template parameter cannot be deduced from initializer list argument.

Because of the special provision in **[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/4**, for `auto init_list = { "narrow string" };` the deduction performed as if you had

```
template <typename U> void f(std::initializer_list<U>);
f({ "narrow string" });
```

Then `U` is happily deduced as `const char*` following the first half of **[temp.deduct.call]/1**, and `auto` as `std::initializer_list<const char*>`.

The situation with the generic lambda call, on the other hand, is equivalent to

```
template <typename T> void f(T);
f({ "narrow string" });
```

This follows the "Otherwise" half of **[temp.deduct.call]/1** whereby `T` is non-deduced context.

Comment: Thanks for persevering through the relevant chapters